# Convert a List of Strings into a single String using ArrayUtils in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have below code

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("one");
test.add("two");
test.add("three");
```

Need output as `"one,two,three"` in a single string using Array Utils. Need a single line solution.

Comment: What is _Array Utils_?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oops ... Dangling reference to a term :(.

Comment: @Nithyn.K ArrayUtils will help to create a new array from two input arrays. However you can easily do it using the technique suggested by laune below.

Comment: @Nithyn.K try to google or search in stackoverflow before asking question.

Answer (score 20):

Use join

```
String joined2 = String.join(",", test );
```

Comment: This requires Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with ArrayUtils. You can use [Apache's StringUtils join function](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Iterable,%20char)) to get the result you want.

```
// result is "one,two,three"
StringUtils.join(test, ',');
```

If you don't want to use a library, you can create this function:

```
public static String joiner(List<String> list, String separator){
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(String term : list) result.append(term + separator);
    return result.deleteCharAt(result.length()-separator.length()).toString();
}
```

Comment: if you have list ["John","Doe"] and separated using " , " , then it will generated "John, Doe,"  . The last comma looks ugly

Comment: Assuming separator is of length 1, `deleteCharAt(result.length()-1).toString()` will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use [`ArrayUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) then you could use [`List.toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) (because `ArrayUtils` is for *arrays*) and a regular expression to remove `{` and `}` on one line like

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
System.out.println(ArrayUtils.toString(test.toArray(new String[0]))
        .replaceAll("[{|}]", ""));
```

Output is (as requested)

> one,two,three

The [`String.join(CharSequence, Iterable<? extends CharSequence>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) suggested by [@Vishnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074750/vishnu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623269/2970947) offers a solution that eschews `ArrayUtils` (but is arguable *better*, assuming you can use it) with

```
String joined2 = String.join(",", test);
System.out.println(joined2);
```

which outputs the same.

Comment: All this extra code... Simply `test.toString().replaceAll( "[\\]\\[ ]", "" )` is not enough?

Comment: @laune Only if you can skip using `ArrayUtils`, and Vishnu has the right idea there (if you can use it).

Answer (score -1):

```
       List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        test.add("one");
        test.add("two");
        test.add("three");
       Iterator it = test.iterator();

       while(it.hasNext()){

      String s=it.next();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     sb.append(s);
}
```